# Why unit test don`t update db?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.4

I have a method that does update query in to db. If the request is sent from the user interface then everything is fine, but if the request from the unit test then the record in the database is not updated.

The update query inside the mthod looks like this

```
          $game_periods_table = DB::table('game_periods')->where('id', $id);
          $current_update_array = [];

          if(array_key_exists('A', $count_throws)){
              $current_update_array['count_throws_a'] =  $count_throws['A'];
          }

          if(array_key_exists('B', $count_throws)){
              $current_update_array['count_throws_b'] =  $count_throws['B'];
          }

          $current_update_array['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

          $game_periods_table->update($current_update_array);
```

and my unit test looks like

```
protected $bgame;
protected $game_id = 95;

public function setUp(){
    parent::setUp();

    $game = new Game();
    $game = $game::find($this->game_id);

    if(is_null($game)){
        $this->fail('Game is not found!');
    }

    $this->bgame = new BGame($game);
}

public function testUpdateThrows(){
    $test_array = [
        'first_period_throws' => ['A' => 1, 'B' => 2],
        'second_period_throws' => ['A' => 3, 'B' => 4],
        'third_period_throws' => ['A' => 5, 'B' => 6],
        'ot_period_throws' => ['A' => 7, 'B' => 8],
    ];

    $this->assertTrue($this->bgame->updateThrows($test_array));
}`
```

The test result is OK, but why my record is doesn`t update ?

From unit tests i use test db, but it is exactly the same as main db.

Comment: Do you use `DatabaseMigrations` ? if you do then the test db gets cleared on each test and won't retain any data. Same with `DatabaseTransactions`, it'll reset the records after the test completion.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two factors to this, the first being that you very well might be using a separate database for tests. Most importantly it looks as if you did not copy your full test file but it has to do with `use DatabaseTransactions` or `use DatabaseMigrations`. You can read more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) but the basic concept is that after every test the database transaction will either be rolled back or the migrations will all be re-run.

> One option is to rollback the database after each test and migrate it
>   before the next test. Laravel provides a simple DatabaseMigrations
>   trait that will automatically handle this for you. Another option is
>   to wrap every test case in a database transaction. Again, Laravel
>   provides a convenient DatabaseTransactions trait that will
>   automatically handle this.

If you want to check if you are using a separate database for your tests just go into your `phpunit.xml` file and look for your `db_connection` while should look like this:

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
```